# Are the actual lines on the ground defined by the actual white paint on the grass or by some laser beam?

Tags: football

Follow-up of [Why was Japan's second goal in the WC 2022 Japan-Spain match deemed to be valid?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/28518/1832): are the actual lines on the ground defined by the actual white paint on the grass or by some laser beam (or some other way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/worldcup/comments/zc03c5/are_the_actual_lines_on_the_ground_defined_by_the/iyud636/?context=3,  the actual lines on the ground defined by the actual white paint.

Comment: Reddit threads are not the LOTG.

Comment: @Nij true, a reference to the rules would be preferable.